# Worker role using event hubs gives 'No connection handler was found for virtual host'

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have a worker role that uses an EventProcessorHost to ingest data from an EventHub. I frequently receive error messages of the following kind:

Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: 
 No connection handler was found for virtual host 'myservicebusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net:42777'. Remote container id is 'f37c72ee313c4d658588ad9855773e51'. TrackingId:1d200122575745cc89bb714ffd533b6d_B5_B5, SystemTracker:SharedConnectionListener, Timestamp:8/29/2016 6:13:45 AM
    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception exception)
    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.Parallel.TaskHelpers.EndAsyncResult(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

I can't seem to find a way to catch this exception. It seems I can just ignore the error because everything works as expected (I had previously mentioned here that it was dropping messages because of this error, but I have since found out that a bug in the software that sends the messages caused this problem), however I would like to know what causes these errors, since they are clogging up my logging now and then.

Can anyone shed some light on the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Event Hub partitions are distributed across multiple servers. They sometimes move due to load balancing, upgrade and other reasons. When this happens, the client connection is lost with this error. The connection will be reestablished very quickly so you should not see any issues with message processing. It is safe to ignore this communication error.

Comment: Somehow I overlooked your answer to my question. I have marked it as answered now.